# GNU Make grouped targets are not grouped

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying out GNU Make grouped targets and seem to misunderstand something, because the targets are not grouped as I'd expect. Here is my makefile:

```
all: foo bar
.PHONY: foo bar
foo bar &:
        @echo grouped target run for \"target\" $@
```

And output:

```
$ make
grouped target run for "target" foo
grouped target run for "target" bar
```

The recipe is run for each target, hence not grouped. What am I missing here?

GNU Make version 4.2.1.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't shoot yourself in the foot? Your example defines `all` as the default target and that target depends on _both foo_ and _bar_.  In other words, `all` means do both `foo` and `bar`. If you remove `all: foo bar` from the above so `foo bar &` are the default, you'll see different results.

Comment: @AndrewFalanga The make default target is the first target, not all targets in the first rule. Having `foo bar &` as the first rule makes `foo` the default target.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Never mind, turns out grouped target is a 4.3 feature.

Source (not official release notes): https://linuxreviews.org/GNU_make_4.3_Is_Released

Comment: Here are the release notes: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/make-w32/2020-01/msg00001.html